# How to get xml response from URL

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to get an xml response from a URL and parse it using a class, which is pretty simple. But these are the errors I am getting:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/...
```

This is the errors I get if I try using

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity
Warning: simplexml_load_file(url) failed to open stream: Cannot allocate memory in /Applications/MAMP/......
```

I have tried using different combinations of simplexml_load_string or simplexml_load_file and sometimes they work but most of the time they are creating the errors above. I have also tried using cURL but still the same errors exists like "Trying to get property of non-object in" but sometimes its able to get xml response and parse it. Does anybody know how I can fix these errors. Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

$curl = curl_init();

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8'
));

$getData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($getData);
// $xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement($getData);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($getData);
print_r($xml);
// // $xml = simplexml_load_file($getData);

$response = new ApiResponse($xml->{'status-code'}, $xml->{'status-code-description'}, $xml->{'data'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will display all data from the sample API XML response (the url). Using `simplexml_load_file()`, interprets the XML data into an object. Which then you can use it.

```
<?php

$html = "";

$url = "http://demo.cakemarketing.com/api/1/get.asmx/Advertisers?api_key=dNJFmId9rI";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

for($i = 0; $i < count($xml);$i++){

      echo $xml->Advertiser[$i]->advertiser_name."<br/>";

}

?>
```

[more details](http://anytch.com/getting-xml-response-data-with-php/)

Also if your getting `Trying to get property of non-object`error, probably your getting unavailable data to your XML. The code will make you understand, if, of course you will understand it :-D